# Make sure you correctly excluded object type variables in your second call of .describe()

Tags: python, pandas, describe

I am performing a topic in datacamp as follows:

> Exploring Your Data Now you'll perform some data exploration using the
>   Python pandas module. To get a sense of the data, you'll output
>   statistics such as mean, median, count, and percentiles. The DataFrame
>   recent_grads is still in your workspace

The objectives of the title hope are as follows:

> ```
> Print the .dtypes of your data so that you know what each column contains.
> Output basic summary statistics using a single pandas function.
> With the same function from before, summary statistics for all columns that aren't of type object.
> ```

My code is as follows

```
# Print .dtypes
print(recent_grads.dtypes)
# Output summary statistics
print(recent_grads.describe())
# Exclude data of type object
print(recent_grads.describe(exclude='object'))
```

However, the error message that appears is as follows

> Make sure you correctly excluded object type variables in your second
>   call of .describe()

May I ask which part of the link is wrong, trouble assistance, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter `exclude` of the `describe()` method requires a *list-like of dtypes*.

Please see the documentation: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html

So, in your case, the correct call would be `recent_grads.describe(exclude=['object'])`